# Сброс интерфейса на начальный вид

Tags: android-studio, android

Господа, случилось непонятное! После несознательных манипуляций с клавиатурой интерфес принял вид, малопригодный для нормальной работы: остались только верхняя строка меню и текст кода `activity_main.xml`.
Мякотка в сабже.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать самым маленьким и тупым? =Р

Comment: @L0hnes, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @L0hnes, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Сейчас выглядит так. Хочу, что бы стало, как раньше.) http://fastpic.ru/view/64/2014/1024/b0e0f253f4c73b207decc5fd75eadb8b.jpg.html

Comment: Первый абзац моего ответа должен полностью решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Хочу, что бы стало как раньше)

www.technotalkative.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Darcula-theme-Android-studio1.png

Comment: Вы сделали то, что я писал в ответе? Если нет, то делайте, оно поможет. ) Если да и при этом ещё не все так хорошо, как раньше, - показывайте текущий скриншот.

Answer (score 2):

Идете в меню View, и там последовательно выбираете Tool Bar, Toolbutton, Status bar, Navigation bar.

Если меню недоступно (всякое бывает), жмете Ctrl+Shift+A, и появившемся списке набираете нужный пункт меню (имя).

Вполне возможно, что Вы включили так называемый Presentation Mode или Full Screen. Их также просто отключить через Ctrl+Shift+A.